# Can email clients still connect to Yahoo safely?

Tags: security, yahoo-mail, outlook

When I logged on to the Yahoo Mail web interface it said that it is recommended to disable apps from connecting to it. When I did so, Outlook was no longer able to connect. Also, Yahoo claims to be enabled for two factor authentication but it seems they just have receiving text messages.

Is there a way to enable two factor authentication and still be able to connect with Outlook?

I'm not sure it's possible that Yahoo's this far behind in security so I'm assuming I'm going about it the wrong way.

Comment: I'm sorry for off topic, but Two factor authentication isn't better than old strong password and even give attacker more chances to exploit account (for example: http://www.securityweek.com/two-factor-authentication-bypassed-simple-attacks) As about Yahoo... they lost my trust a long time ago.. and again, they were hacked 2 months ago but only in December they disclose it... What version of Outlook you using? 365 should support 2FA for sure

Comment: @Alex that article is specific to phone-based 2FA. Do you have another example to back up the assertion that all 2FA isn't better than a strong password?

Comment: I thought that the question was about yahoo's 2FA which use "phone-based 2FA". I didn't say that ALL 2FA are bad

Comment: @Alex "Two factor authentication isn't better than old strong password and even give attacker more chances to exploit account" sure sounds like you did

Comment: Let's see: you connected to Yahoo via their web mail interface and got a message from Yahoo saying their own service is insecure; you followed their recommendation to disable apps from connecting and now Outlook can't connect; you enabled 2 factor authentication and you get text messages on your phone.  Nope, you're not doing it the wrong way; that's actually how Yahoo works now.  I'm not sure what they're thinking at Yahoo HQ, but maybe alcohol is a factor.

Comment: @fixer1234 so just to confirm there's no way for a email client to securely connect to yahoo mail? I mean it sounds like a ridiculous question but I'm serious. Obviously Outlook can't receive a text message but doesn't Yahoo have an app specific password?

Comment: This is obviously a reaction (over-reaction?) to their massive hacks.  Maybe their lawyers dreamed it up--make you agree that you know their service is inherently unsafe so that if they're hacked again you can't sue them.  I don't think there's any way to know how secure Yahoo is relative to other providers.  They could have been a hack target just because they're so huge.  If you follow the news, the most secure stuff of the US government is routinely hacked.  Personally, I just assume that nothing is really safe, and am careful with what I put there.